# Django 3: Badly formed URL in password_reset_email.html

Tags: django, email, passwords, reset

I have a Django 3.0.7 app using the default template for sending password reset emails.
For some of our users, the link to reset is badly formed, e.g.:

```
https://foo.bar/accounts/reset/McU4Mw/5no-9cd52590f0943503=
fa3a/
/>
```

While it should be:

```
https://foo.bar/accounts/reset/McU4Mw/5no-9cd52590f0943503fa3a/
```

This second one is whats actually being sent. But, as I said, some users are receiving the first one.
I assume some of my users' email clients are wrecking the text, but what could I do?
I've considered adding a plaintext url to the email, but it's already plaintext.

EDIT: This is a solution I came up with, and it works. Can anyone think of a reason not to do this?

```
urls.py
...
path('accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/<str:extra_chars>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('accounts/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
...
```

EDIT:
Here's the default template:

```
/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans 'Your username, in case you’ve forgotten:' %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Could you also show the template that is being used

Comment: It's the default template in ```/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html```